# Is it possible to create a enumerated data-type that consists of 2 enumerated data types?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say I have two enum data types of commands

```
//  CMD global macros
`define CMD_1_VAL       32'hFACEFACE
`define CMD_2_VAL       16'hBEEF
`define CMD_3_VAL       20'hF000D
`define CMD_4_VAL       12'hCAB
`define CMD_5_VAL       32'hBA5EC0DE

typedef enum logic[31:0] {
                            CMD_1 = `CMD_1_VAL,
                            CMD_2 = `CMD_2_VAL,
                            CMD_3 = `CMD_3_VAL
}   command_set_1;

typedef enum logic[31:0] {
                            CMD_4 = `CMD_4_VAL,
                            CMD_5 = `CMD_5_VAL
}   command_set_2;
```

Is it possible to create an enumerated data type which encapsulates both enum data types that have been defined without the need to create a new enumerated data type which lists out the commands individually? Something similar along the line of this:

```
Pseudocode of what is desired: 
typedef enum logic[31:0] {
                            // include command_set_1 and command_set_2
}   command_set_1_and_2
```

The reason why I wanted this was so that more sets of commands could be added to their respective enumerated data types for reusability and for randomization of all defined commands listed within their enumerated data types using the std::randomize() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compose enumerated types from other enumerations. Nor can you have enumerations of different sizes.

SystemVerilog does have arrays of arrays which means you can build list of variable sized commands and use array concatenation to combine them. However, for randomization,  it would be easier to have a simple list of command numbers in a queue or dynamic array. Then use the `inside` constraint to select from the list of commands. Once you have a command number, you can use an associative array to map the command to its encoding.